# A puzzling click event : Why such behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was recently testing the click event (finding a textbox upon click) of a `<label>` and found something unusual.

In the HTML markup,

- If the `<input>` is inside the `<label>`, the click event on that
  label is firing two times
- If the `<input>` is outside the `<label>`, the click event is
  functioning as expected

To better understand what I'm trying to put forward, please refer to the fiddle at [<kbd>**JS Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/8mzmjn0z/)

I'm baffled because of this and can't figure out the reason behind it. Any takers?

Comment: Look into event bubbling / propagation. http://jsfiddle.net/8mzmjn0z/6/

Comment: Could you share your code? My first guess is that your selector is matching both elements.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Wrapping `input`s in `label`s is often used and is perfectly valid :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa: Quite right. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the `<input>` is inside the `<label>`, the click event on that label is firing two times

Because events 'bubble' up through the DOM, from the element recieving the initial event (the `event.target`, here the `<input />`) through ancestors. Because the listener is attached to the parent of the `<input />` it first fires on the click detected on its descendant, and then again when the click bubbles to itself.

To prevent this, you can use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling.

Because the `event`, in this case, has already bubbled to the `<label>` element at the point that the `alert()`/event-handler is fired, you'll have to explicitly call `event.stopPropagation()` on the `<input />` itself, rather than in the event-handler attached to the `<label>`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('label input').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(".v1 li label").click(function() {
    var ct = $(this).find("input").val();
    alert(ct);
  });

  $(".v2 li label").click(function() {
    var ct = $(this).parent().find("input").val();
    alert(ct);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 10px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
li label {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li input {
  display: none;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><i>input</i> inside <i>label</i></h3>

<ul class="v1">
  <li>
    <label for="l1">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="1" id="l1" />First</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="l2">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="2" id="l2" />Second</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="l3">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="3" id="l3" />Third</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<h3><i>input</i> outside <i>label<i></h3> 
<ul class="v2">
  <li>
    <label for="ll1">Fourth</label>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="4" id="ll1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="ll2">Fifth</label>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="5" id="ll2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="ll3">Sixth</label>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="6" id="ll3" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: Oh my..that makes sense. I wasn't aware of it. Will mark as answer when the time limit lapses. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, click event is propagating from label to input and then again to label, hence you can find two alerts.

You can use below code when we can check the target element tag name and if it is `INPUT` then return otherwise process further.

```
$(".v1 li label").click(function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName=='INPUT')
      return false;
   var ct= $(this).find("input").val();     
   alert("first "+ct);      
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mzmjn0z/11/)**